# mysql.user - list column (privileges) values as records

Tags: mysql, privileges

Need help to list all the privileges a user has (means, with "Y" on the column privileges) from the `select * from mysql.user;` result and have it as 1 column (as **user_priv**) together with **host** and **user** columns

[query test user and its privileges details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISJIT.png)

Would like to turn above result to this one:

```
+------+------+-------------+
| user | host | user_priv   |
+------+------+-------------+
| test | %    | Create_priv |
+------+------+-------------+
| test | %    | Reload_priv |
+------+------+-------------+
| test | %    | ...         |
```

Comment: not able to get your question? Can you explain

Comment: Hi Kandy, sorry lost of proper words to describe it better! I added an image and what result I am hoping for instead

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data you are after by querying the `information_schema`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` table which derives it's data from `mysql`.`user` ([documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-privileges-table.html))

While you won't get the exact format you are after without a bit of string manipulation to separate user and host you will get more readable output for the privilege types.

e.g.

```
SELECT `GRANTEE` as 'USER@HOST', `PRIVILEGE_TYPE` as 'PRIVILEGE' 
FROM `information_schema`.`USER_PRIVILEGES` WHERE `GRANTEE` LIKE '%paul%';
+--------------------+-------------------------+
| USER@HOST          | PRIVILEGE               |
+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 'paul'@'localhost' | SELECT                  |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | INSERT                  |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | UPDATE                  |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | DELETE                  |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | CREATE                  |

...

| 'paul'@'localhost' | DROP                    |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | RELOAD                  |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | EVENT                   |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | TRIGGER                 |
| 'paul'@'localhost' | CREATE TABLESPACE       |
+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

If you want to know if the user can GRANT the privileges, add the column `IS_GRANTABLE` to your query.